# How to plot probability density function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, probability, plotting

I'm trying to get a frequency plot, or PDF (probability density function) plot for my biometrics project in MATLAB.
I have two vectors `genuine_scores` and `impostor_scores`, and I need to have a graph like:

```
x-axis : value of elements
y-axis : frequency of that value
```

So the graph should look like this :
 [image]

I tried `probplot()` but it gives the cumulative distrubition function

I also tried `normpdf();` but it does not make sense to me. Because I'm not interested in a mean value. I just need how frequent each of the value appears in the vector(s).

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Have you tried stairs(x, y)?

Answer (score 1):

I think hist (histogram plot) or bar (bar graph) may do the job.

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/bar.html

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/hist.html

Answer (score 1):

Matlab R2014b has this 'histogram' function which has the 'normalization' property, it may give what you want.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram.html#namevaluepairarguments